react native kotlin error when tried to run application in android emulator
Error occured in react native kotlin compilation

Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
e: file:///Users/dynamicmethods/Documents/Manan_projects/paymentgateway/gateway/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/settings-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactSettingsExtension.kt:43:22 Unresolved reference: files


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please read How to produce minimal reproducible example
